# sugarCRM: Fatal error: Class 'Asakusuma\SugarWrapper\Rest' not found

Tags: php, macos, sugarcrm

I try to run example from https://github.com/asakusuma/SugarCRM-REST-API-Wrapper-Class.
Downloaded, replaced composer.json as recommended author:

```
{
    "require": {
        "asakusuma/sugarcrm-wrapper": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

then ran compose:

[image]

as you can see all right:

[image]

Uploaded to my sugarCRM CE 6.5.17 and run:

[image]

As you can see i got error.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I only know how to make it work. I had the same problem.

I added the following to a new line of my php file after the \<\?\php line

include('./vendor/autoload.php');